# Insert method in Priority Queue with ArrayList

Tags: java, methods, queue

I wrote these method to insert elements into an ArrayList:

```
public void insert(E element) {
    queue.add(size(), element);
    siftUp(size() - 1);
}

public void siftUp(int size) {
    E elem = queue.get(size);
    for (; size > 0 && (elem.compareTo(queue.get(size / 2)) == 1); size /= 2) {
        queue.add(size, queue.get(size/2));
    }
    queue.add(size, elem);
}
```

But one I execute them with a test, it insert multiple items and I don't know why:

```
@Test
public void testInsert_OneEl() {
    PriorityQueue queue = new PriorityQueue();
    Integer[] arrayExp = {5};
    queue.insert(5);
    assertArrayEquals(arrayExp, queue.getQueue().toArray());
}
```

The error is:

```
testInsert_OneEl(priorityqueue.QueueTests): array lengths differed, expected.length=1 actual.length=2".
```

Comment: Well, I see you calling `queue.add` **at least** twice whenever `insert` is called.

Comment: From [the documentation onf `ArrayList#add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-): "*Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. **Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices)**.*" In plain english: with each call to `add(int index, E element)`, your array will increase in size instead of overriding the value at the `i`th index.

Comment: So, does the index shift +1 even if I'm adding the element in a position which is occupied by another element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Turing85
My array increase +1 because I call the method "add" twice.

Comment: If you were calling it twice, it would increase by two.